# Surface pro 4 usb alternative

Tags: usb

My surface pro usb died. Microsoft says I have to replace. I don’t want to buy a new one. 
Is there any device that connects with the Bluetooth of the laptop and act as an input for usb device?

I desperately need to connect usb devices to my pro. The surface dock has usb, but at $200, it is overpriced.

Thanks for any other suggestions.

Comment: What does Microsoft say you have to replace? What is the actual problem with the USB? What USB devices are you needing to connect to your Surface Pro?

Comment: They asked me to replace the surface pro as USB cannot be repaired. Once I was using a USB hub and it seems that the hub shorted it out. Microsoft service center too couldn't find the problem, they simply said they cannot use their diagnostic USB in my laptop and therefore USB is not working. My son uses USB for his external microphones etc.Not everything is Bluetooth, hence finding it very difficult to have lost the only USB on this.